# RSQLite: how to make not equal statement?

Tags: r, rsqlite

I would like to make the following statement:

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB 
FROM tableA 
WHERE fielb != 'cond' GROUP BY fieldA.
```

This statement works with **SQLite Manager** but does not work in **RSQLite**.

Could you please help me?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: How does it not work?  You can always try the ANSI standard `<>` instead of `!=`.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been closed as not reproducible?

Answer (score 2):

To me, `!=` works as it should. Here is an example:

```
data(USArrests)
library(RSQLite)
m <- dbDriver("SQLite")
tfile <- tempfile()
con <- dbConnect(m, dbname = tfile)
dbWriteTable(con, "USArrests", USArrests)
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from USArrests where row_names != 'Alaska'")
d <- fetch(rs, n = -1)      # extract all remaining data
setdiff(row.names(USArrests), d$row_names)
# [1] "Alaska"

dbHasCompleted(rs)
dbClearResult(rs)
dbListTables(con)
dbDisconnect(con)
file.remove(tfile)
```